# Update the array values using produce in immer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, immer.js

I am trying to update the array values using produce in immer but draft is undefined for me. Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong?

```
export const getCustomers = (customers) => (dispatch, getState) => { 
  const activeCustomers = produce(customers, (draft) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < customers.length; i += 1) {
      draft.customers[i].position= i;
    }
  });

//I keep getting that error that draft.customers[i] is undefined
```

What am I doing wrong. Keep getting that error that draft.customers[i] is undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well draft is a `clone` of `customers` themselves so it doesn't include costumers,
try this:

```
export const getCustomers = (customers) => (dispatch, getState) => { 
  const activeCustomers = produce(customers, (draft) => {
    for (let i = 0; i < draft.length; i ++) {
      draft[i].position= i;
    }
  });
```